# "Unable to read file [input.json]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.json'" When running local predict

Tags: json, scikit-learn, cloud, gcloud, platform

I am following the Google Cloud guide to upload my prediction model via this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart?fbclid=IwAR1HjyGajUj-IiiEeshmViiN3GK97sJgwO1h4O0R3yVYubtwlNOhd1v-0Vs

Both the input.json file and the model.pkl file is placed directly in my bucket.

When trying to do a local prediction test, which can be seen in the code bit:

```
gcloud ai-platform local predict --model-dir=$MODEL_DIR \
    --json-instances $INPUT_FILE \
    --framework $FRAMEWORK
```

I get the following error:
"Unable to read file [input.json]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.json'"

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

`${INPUT_FILE}` should be locally in the directory(`pwd`) from where you run the `gcloud` command.

The `gcloud` command uploads `${INPUT_FILE}` from your local machine to the prediction service.

The prediction service uses your model (which is in the Cloud Storage bucket `${MODEL_DIR}`).

Comment: Hi DazWilkin. Thank you for your answer. Sadly, I still fail to make it work.  I can find the file when using the "gsutil ls" command, so it should be placed the in the right spot. Additional information: I am using the shell in the browser, and I have previously been able to find the file.

Comment: OK. I'm going to try this for myself and will report back.

Comment: I assume when you say "using the shell in the browser" that you're referring to Google Cloud Shell. I will use that too.

Comment: OK. It worked for me although I had some other challenges with the documentation. What is the result of `ls -l` (within the same directory where you run `gcloud ai-platform...`? What about `echo ${MODEL_DIR} ${INPUT_FILE} ${FRAMEWORK}`?

Comment: Hi DazWilkin. Thanks a lot. When I run ```ls -1``` I get "FlaskApi
Model
README-cloudshell.txt". When running echo I get "gs://ml-boi-model/ input.json SCIKIT_LEARN"

Comment: OK. There's no `input.json` listed from that first command. It appears you haven't created the file. Try something like `nano input.json`, paste the values shown into the file, save it (CTRL-X) and then try running the `gcloud` command again.